# fail to install nuget package zlib in a visual studio project

Tags: .net, nuget, zlib

I want to test the "zlib" package on NuGet from CoApp. the version I tested in 1.2.8.1. when I tried to install the package on a test project in Visual Studio 2012, it produces the following error message:

> install-package : Could not install package 'zlib.redist 1.2.8.1'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more  information, contact the package author. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + install-package zlib
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Has any one encountered the similar issue? I have tried to change my target framework to the most current one 4.5 to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like these packages do not target .NET framework. They are meant to be used in C/C++ projects. You may want to use [zlib.net package](https://nuget.org/packages/zlib.net).

Comment: Thanks for reformatting my question. I understand your point. However, the redistributable is only installed as a companion of the "zlib" package. In other words, I tried to install zlib package, and the installer is installing the companion package zlib (redistributable) which is a different package, and this package is the one that you referred to in your answer that is not meant to be installed on its own. I did not try to install zlib.redist directly.

Comment: @user2468956 zlib.redist package is a dependency of zlib package so NuGet will try to install it first. zlib package does not  target .NET framework either. You can install these packages in a C++ project.